# Column data to shapefiles

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes

I'm using QGIS 2.8 and am trying to take a shapefile that has multiple column data and display that as individual shapes.

For example...

I have a soil test data table that includes pH, P, K, Fe, Zn and so on and I need a simple way to explode that info so I can view each one independently.  I have read posts that say I should transpose the data in Excel but is there a simpler way via a script or plugin?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You don't need to change the data, just the style ...

Comment: You'd need to create however many copies of the shapefile that you have attributes, and delete all but the desired attribute. But there's really no reason to do this (and many reasons **not** to), as you could add the same shapefile multiple times as different layers, each symbolized on a different attribute, then simply turn them on and off depending on which one you want to examine. Is that what you're trying to do, just see a map of the values for one given attribute?

Comment: Copying the shapefile multiple times as stated above was my plan B.  I was just hoping for a quicker way to parse out the data.  With plan B I would have to copy the shp file 14 times and then rename each copy to the desired attribute. That works just fine but I have many datasets that I need to perform this on and was hoping for a short cut.

Comment: I'm still not understanding *why* you would want or need to do this - I can see nothing but downsides to storing your data this way. However it would be possible to build a script or model that could make a copy and delete all but a particular attribute. Might even be one out there - I know there's a solution that can split all features with a common attribute value to new shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can script almost everything. QGIS itself (nor any other GIS from my knowledge) does not allow to view individual columns. The colums give information about the shapefile. I would recommend splitting the columns in Excel/Access to separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

One of the quicker (and scriptable) ways to manipulate shapefiles is to use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).  For example, to keep just the column named 'name' do:

```
ogr2ogr \
-f 'ESRI Shapefile' \
-select name \
dest.shp \
source.shp
```

This is formatted for readability in a bash shell, but you can just as easily remove the slashes and write it all on one line.  Multiple output fields are comma separated.